# strncmp() gives a false positive

Tags: c, getline, strncmp

I have been expirencing an issue with strncmp and getline... so a i made a little test app. strncmp gives false positives and i can't figure out what i am doing wrong.

this is the program

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fp=NULL;
char uname[4]="test";
char *confline=NULL;
size_t conflinelength=0;
int datlength;

main()
{
    datlength=4;
    fp=fopen("test.txt","r+");
    while (getline(&confline,&conflinelength,fp)!=-1)
    {
        if (strncmp(confline,uname,(datlength-1))==0);
        {
            printf("match\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("no match\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

and this is "test.txt"...

```
bjklas
```

and the program outputs

```
match
```

Comment: `char uname[4]="test";` is OK as `datlength=4`, but suggest `char uname[]="test";`.  Also `printf("match\n");` should be followed by `fclose(fp);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (strncmp(confline,uname,(datlength-1))==0);
    printf("match\n");
```

is equivalent to

```
if (strncmp(confline,uname,(datlength-1))==0)
    ;
printf("match\n");
```

You need to remove the `;` from the end of your `if` line

Answer (score 3):

```
if (strncmp(confline,uname,(datlength-1))==0);
                                             ^ roh-roh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would have used`char uname[5]="test";` this line would have automatically appended the '\0', making it a C string, but with *only 4 spaces* allocated, it couldn't.  Instead, it is an unterminated char array...

`char uname[4]="test";` results in an unterminated set of chars, i.e. not a C string. i.e. "|t|e|s|t|"
This will compile, but it cannot be processed by some string functions, (strcmp, strlen,etc) resulting in run-time errors.

Suggest `char uname[]="test";`  this will automatically take care of appending the NULL terminator yielding a C string: "|t|e|s|t|\0|".  This method is a preferred way to initialize char arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is your typo when you put the semicolon ; at the end of if condition instead of its statement, i.e. right after the curve bracket }

Out of interest, I would prefer using fgets because getline is not in a standard C library

Comment: are you referring to the line _if (strncmp(confline,uname,(datlength-1))==0);_ ?